# Do TakeWhile and LengthWhile work with Greater?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
TakeWhile[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, # > 3 &]
```

gives me `{}`.

Similarly `LengthWhile[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, # > 3 &]`
gives me `0`.

I don't know what is going wrong here. Why is `Greater` not working with `TakeWhile` and `LengthWhile`?

I am using *Mathematica* 10.0.2.

Comment: Umm, since the first value *is not* greater than 3, there are no values to take. No values = 0 values = empty list. What's the question?

Comment: sorry my bad, i was thinking it should run over the entire list and give me a subset of matched elements.

Comment: I think perhaps `Select` is what your after, and `Count` for "length"...

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust, you have figured out the response to your "why" question by reading the comments.
For your convenience here some very common ways for selecting elements from a list.

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, x_?(# > 3 &)]
Cases[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, x_ /; x > 3]
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, # > 3 &]

(*{4,5}*)
```

Welcome to Mathematica !!!